# Azure-Function-Express - cannot resolve URI components from *segments

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am using the `azure-function-express` node module. The documentation mentions the use of `{*segments}` but does not provide much context to it.

Here is how my `function.json` file looks like:

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "route": "{*segments}",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "name": "inputDocument",
      "databaseName": "GBuckets",
      "collectionName": "buckets",
      "sqlQuery": "select *  from GBuckets c join b in c.buckets where b.bucketid = {bucketId}",
      "connectionStringSetting": "bucketsdb",
      "direction": "in"
    }

  ]
}
```

The `bucketId` is supposed to come in as a part of the `{*segments}`, and my node.js code does handle it.

However when I am trying to run this code, it is throwing the following error:

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.func_name. System.Private.CoreLib: The given key 'bucketId' was not present in the dictionary.
```

Obviously, it is not able to resolve the 'bucketId' from the `function.json` file. 
How do I remedy this without having to go the CosmosClient route?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please open an issue here https://github.com/yvele/azure-function-express/issues

Answer (score 0):

This might not work with azure-functions-express. Azure Functions can't infer what "bucketId" is from the path unless it is named. azure-functions-express requires wild card access, so they are incompatible.

I'd recommend using the Cosmos SDK directly, instead, if you want to keep using azure-functions-express. There is a new version of it (@azure/cosmos) which is modern with promises/etc. and it's really good. (but I'm biased because I wrote it...)